# Ruby: How to convert IP range to array of IP's

Tags: ruby, ip

Is there any easy way to convert IP range to array of IPs?

```
def convertIPrange (start_ip, end_ip)
 #output: array of ips end
end
```

e.g. input

```
('192.168.1.105', '192.168.1.108')
```

output

```
['192.168.1.105','192.158.1.106','192.158.1.107','192.158.1.108']
```

Comment: While it's easy to convert a range to an array, be *very* careful doing so. A Range is a very compact and efficient way to store the endpoints because it's ONLY the endpoints. An Array, on the other hand, is every point, including all the ones in-between, which all consume memory. Consider the implications of an Array containing the IPs in a /8 CIDR. It only gets worse if it's a larger network or you're dealing with IPv6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Ruby standard library [`IPAddr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html)

```
# I would suggest naming your function using underscore rather than camelcase
# because of Ruby naming conventions
#
require 'ipaddr'

def convert_ip_range(start_ip, end_ip)
  start_ip = IPAddr.new(start_ip)
  end_ip   = IPAddr.new(end_ip)

  # map to_s if you like, you can also call to_a, 
  # IPAddrs have some neat functions regarding IPs, 
  # be sure to check them out
  #
  (start_ip..end_ip).map(&:to_s) 
end
```

Comment: +1 for the only answer doing the right thing and using IPAddr. The [IPAddress](https://github.com/bluemonk/ipaddress) gem is even more full-featured, especially when doing network manipulations.

Comment: +1, However IPAddr is not in core, but in standard lib.

Comment: The reason this is the right answer, is that IPAddr will automatically deal with IP ranges where it's not just the last octet changing. It'll result in a large array but it'll still do the right thing.

Comment: @theTinMan So does my answer.

Comment: @steenslag Thanks, I had dem mixed up. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you! (just adding characters here, if not, StackOverflow doesn't allow me to thank you, it's OK now, bye)

Answer (score 2):

```
def convertIPrange first, last
  first, last = [first, last]
    .map{|s| s.split(".").inject(0){|i, s| i = 256 * i + s.to_i}}
  (first..last).map do |q|
    a = []
    (q, r = q.divmod(256)) && a.unshift(r) until q.zero?
    a.join(".")
  end
end

convertIPrange('192.168.1.105', '192.168.1.108')
# => ["192.168.1.105", "192.168.1.106", "192.168.1.107", "192.168.1.108"]

convertIPrange('192.255.255.254', '193.0.0.1')
# => ["192.255.255.254", "192.255.255.255", "193.0.0.0", "193.0.0.1"]
```

Comment: `s/convertIPrange/convert_ip_range/`

Comment: @theTinMan I don't like the method name, but that is what the OP is asking. If I write a method with a different name, it would not be answering the OP's question.

Comment: @theTinMan You wrote that another answer is the only one doing the right thing. What is wrong with this one?

Comment: While it'll work, it's not taking advantage of the built-in Class, which offers a number of additional features including checks to see if it is a valid IP being submitted. Try `puts convertIPrange('0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.256')`.

Comment: @theTinMan The OP did not mention that it may come from user input, so I assumed the values are valid. Although, I did not know of the library, and agree that using it is better.